# Essential language paradigms for professional developer

Tags: programming-languages, paradigms

So I guess most (all?) programmers start out learning a mainly imperative/ procedural programming paradigm, and probably learnt some form of **object-oriented programming** fairly shortly after that. I've read plenty of questions on stackoverflow suggesting **functional programming** is increasingly important for improved concurrency/ parallelism. Also that programmers should learn many paradigms to improve their skills and broaden their perspectives.

What are some other paradigms (and languages that use it) that are really beneficial to development skills?

Comment: As a poll type question which is also quite subjective, I would change the question to be community wiki if you want it to remain open and get any answers.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.. how do I do that? (sorry, still fairly new here)

Answer (score 1):

There's possibly an argument for looking at a logic language such as [Prolog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog).  Other than that, within the universe of functional programming languages there are many varieties (e.g. contrast Haskell, ML, Scala and Scheme).  You might want to explore the various dimensions in terms of things like type systems, laziness and syntax.